# dialog box not showing error

Tags: jquery

I`m having the following error .  Why am I having this error and how can I solve it?

> $("SelectProject").dialog is not a function
>   http://localhost:1419/Customer
>   Line 57
>
> $("#SelectProject").dialog is not a function
>   http://localhost:1419/Customer
>   Line 69

My codes are as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#project_link").click(function() {
        $('SelectProject').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });

    $('#SelectProject').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 800,
        position: [130, 200],
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Accept": function() {

                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the jQuery UI script file? "dialog()" is the jQuery UI method.

You can include this library like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

This tag you need to put in the <head> section of you html document.

Comment: Also you may need to include some CSS files (with jQuery UI widgets styles). You may find out more information about this framework here: http://jqueryui.com/.

Comment: the error has disappeared with the script used.  But still the dialog isn`t being displayed.

Comment: Did you include jQuery CSS-styles file? Without it you can't see dialogbox, because it will be transparent. Please, carefully read the jqueryui.com and their tutorials: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/, http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started#Basic_overview:_using_jQuery_UI_on_a_web_page

Answer (score 0):

Also, your selector in your click function looks wrong it should be:

```
$('#SelectProject').dialog('open');
```

(Assuming the element has an id of SelectProject)